# (Faire des) « effets de toge/manche » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, habillement

- Que signifie « *effets de [toge](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toge)* » et quelle en est l'origine ?
- Est-ce une variante des « *effets de [manche](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/manche/49034/locution)* » [faire des] ?
- Existe-t-il d'autres types d'*effets de* [nom de (partie de) vêtement] ?

---

On ne trouve aucune référence au *Larousse*, *TLFi*, *DHLF* etc. Quelqu'un a posé la question [ailleurs](http://www.guichetdusavoir.org/viewtopic.php?t=29230), et c'est là qu'on a fait une association entre les *effets de toge* et *faire des effets de manche*, qu'au final on n'a pas réussi à étayer non plus. Un [*ngram*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=effets%20de%20toge%2Ceffets%20de%20manche&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ceffets%20de%20toge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceffets%20de%20manche%3B%2Cc0) en illustre l'emploi (faiblement) mais on n'a aucune définition ni explication de l'origine de ces expressions... L'idée qu'une personne *fasse des effets de*, le cas échéant, est aussi particulière...

Comment: Où avez vous trouvé cette expression ? Dans quel contexte ?

Comment: Personnellement en cherchant un peu j'ai trouvé effectivement plusieurs références à "effets de manche" et "effets de toge". Le sens est apparemment le même. "Effets de manche" est, toujours d'après ce que j'ai compris, des gestes exagérés, voir grandiloquents pour illustrer un propos. Je trouve la référence à "effets de toge" au [québec](https://www.barreaudemontreal.qc.ca/loads/DocumentsActivites/Colloque20110119/B.%20Joly_2011-01-19.pdf) , serait-ce une expression plus "locale" ? autre référence québécoise [ici](http://www.nadeaubellavance.com/2015/10/02/debats-politiques/)

Comment: Sous l'illustration du _ngram_ le lien vers _effets de toge_ contient des exemples dont ceux de Lionel Bourg, Maurice Brun (ils sont Français), ainsi que L'Express :  « _Privé de ses effets de toge, Cicéron ne serait-il qu'un politicien vaniteux, versatile et couard ?_ » Je peux trouver un sens dans tous les contextes, mais je comprends mal pourquoi ce n'est pas documenté, et ces autres nuances que j'aborde... L'une pourrait être une variante régionale de l'autre, étant la manche de la première, qui sait ! Merci.

Comment: D'accord. Je continue à chercher, peut-être vais-je trouver la solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je n'ai pas de références précises, mais en attendant une réponse mieux documentée : *effets de manche* renvoie aux manches très larges des robes des avocats, *effets de toge* à la toge des patriciens romains. Il ne faut pas chercher plus loin la différence entre les deux : les deux ont le même sens et désignent des effets oratoires exagérés et superficiels, tant au niveau de la gestuelle que des figures de style ou de l'intonation, qui masquent la faiblesse du fond. Il s'agit simplement de choisir ce qu'on veut évoquer entre la plaidoirie d'un avocat et celle d'un sénateur romain.

Pour d'autres *effets de [vêtement]*, je n'en ai jamais rencontré d'exemple, et je ne pense pas qu'il y en existe, en tout cas pas idiomatiques. À part la toge romaine, il n'y a pas d'exemple d'un orateur connu agitant autre chose que ses manches (des bracelets, peut-être ?).

Comment: Les effets de toge seraient donc plus pour la politique alors que l'on trouverait effets de manche dans le champ lexical de la justice ?

Comment: L'usage d'*effet* et à rapprocher de celui d'*effet de style* ou d'*effets spéciaux* par exemple. Ce n'est pas une expression neutre désignant simplement un mouvement de manche, mais une expression péjorative indiquant que l'attitude, l'intonation, les gestes, le vocabulaire, les figures de style, bref toute la forme du discours, sont exagérés et théâtraux pour masquer la vacuité du fond. Un *mouvement* n'a pas la connotation d'illusion que peut avoir *effet*.

Comment: _en attendant une réponse mieux documentée_... ça ne va pas nécessairement se produire. Le truc sur la statue m'a ébranlé haha :  [_Aussi quoique tout le monde connaisse l'effet que produit la toge sur les statues..._](https://books.google.com/books?id=vrAHAAAAIAAJ&dq=effets%20de%20toge&pg=PA291#v=onepage&q=effets%20de%20toge&f=false), j'ai toujours pensé que l'effet c'était un mouvement, mais au final l'origine pourrait être l'effet de la toge sur le corps, sur le _statutaire_ comme dirait l'autre. Du magnanime à l'idée d'attitude affectée, de vouloir donner cette impression. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Je rapprocherais la construction des expression « effets de manches » ou « effets de toge » à celle de l'expression « effets de rênes ».

**Effet** vient du latin *effectus* « exécution, réalisation », « vertu, force » et « résultat ».

> Du sens de « résultat » sont issus plusieurs emplois spéciaux : en équitation (1690, Furetière) *effet* désigne l'action de la main, de la jambe qui sert à conduire le cheval (*effets de rênes*) ; au billard (XIX<sup>e</sup> s. ; 1968 J. Verne in *T.L.F.*, mettre de l'effet, effet (de queue) ; (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey)

De la même façon que le cavalier fait des effets de rênes pour générer des réactions sur sa monture on peut voir l'« effet de manches »/« l'effet de toge » comme un mouvement du membre supérieur destiné à agiter sa manche (d'autant plus spectaculaire que la manche est large) ou sa toge, dans le but d'obtenir une réaction, une impression (au sens d'impressionner, marquer) sur son auditoire.

Une autre alternative est de prendre le mot *effet* au sens de « exécution, réalisation » :

> Au pluriel le mot s'emploie au sens d'« attitude affectée pour produire des effets » (1834, *effets de cils, effets de voix*) (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey)

En fait il me semble que les deux définitions se rejoignent dans la mesure où il y a utilisation d'un instrument (cils, voix, rênes, toge...) pour susciter une réaction sur la personne, l'animal auquel on s'adresse.

Comment: d'où vient alors le sens péjoratif de l'expression ? Dans les articles que j'ai eu l'occasion de lire, cette expression est toujours utilisée de manière négative, pour expliciter que l'avocat/le politicien/etc... a utilisé la forme pour cacher le manque de fond.

Comment: @GautierC  Dire de quelqu'un qu'il a une attitude affecté me semble plutôt péjoratif.  **Affecté** « Qui manifeste de l'affectation, qui manque de simplicité naturelle et parfois de sincérité. » ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affect%C3%A9)). Mais de toute façon je ne réponds que sur la partie de la question « origine et autres effets », vu que sur le sens il y a déjà une réponse que la mienne ne contredit en rien.

Comment: d'accord, je comprend ! Oui, c'était juste par curiosité personnelle

Comment: @SurvenantLazurite À part effet de manche...  En un seul mot, non, je ne vois pas.

Comment: Merci ! Vous avez bien identifié cette _attitude affectée_, et l'idée d'impressionner. Au Barreau de Montréal j'ai trouvé un document avec des conseils aux nouveaux avocats à l'effet d'éviter les effets de toge, par exemple, mais si je demandais d'où ça provient et pourquoi c'est la toge ou la manche, j'ai l'impression qu'on va me broder une paire de mitoufles. J'admets personnellement n'avoir aucune idée exacte d'où ça vient même si vos réponses sont bien intéressantes et donnent une bonne idée. Mais comme j'ai dit ailleurs, la _statue_, qu'est-ce que c'est que cette affaire-là !? Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Plutôt que l'origine, si on veut considérer comment se concrétisent les "effets de toge" on n'a qu'à regarder ce qui se passe dans notre culture.

Dans une cour de justice, quand la toge primordiale (le juge) entre dans la salle, tout le monde retire sa gomme à mâcher, se tait et se lève pour ne se rasseoir que lorsque la toge principale est assise. À partir de là, seule la toge principale a droit de parole qu'elle délègue temporairement à qui elle veut. Plus souvent qu'autrement, c'est aux toges mineures (avocats) qu'elle le délègue. Les toges mineures ont beaucoup de latitude dans l'utilisation de ce droit de parole; elles peuvent en déléguer une partie à des "sans toge", mais il s'agit alors d'un droit très restreint car ceux-ci ne peuvent strictement que répondre aux questions posées par les toges. La toge principale a le mot de la fin: quand elle dit que tout est terminé, c'est terminé, et ses décisions prennent force de loi.

Dans une époque pas si lointaine, la toge de nos évêques, curés et religieux enseignants (qu'on désigne sous le nom de "soutane") avait un peu beaucoup le même effet.

Et naturellement, comme il y a des manipulateurs partout dans notre société, il y a plein de gens qui croient que certains effets de leur statut leur confère un pouvoir et même un droit... et ils en abusent.